# How to "if-else" component in vue router?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm currently using vue with [vue-router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-router). And I have a little problem to fix, maybe you could help.

The outcome that I want is, after I logged-in, I want to use **Auth.vue** as parent and **Home.vue** as it content. And if the user is unauthenticated/has logged out I will use **Guest.vue** with **Welcome.vue** as it content. I want them both use same path `/`.

Now the code below works fine after logging-in, the problem is after I logged out, even the `user.isLoggedIn()` is false it still using **Auth.vue** & **Home.vue**

Any suggestion how to achieve this?

---

Now here is my **router.js**

```
{
    path: '/login',
    name: 'login',
    component:  () => import('./Login'),
},

{
    path: '/',
    component:  () => {
        if(user.isLoggedIn()) { 
            return import('./views/layouts/Auth');
        }else {
            return import('./views/layouts/Guest');
        }
    },
    children: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'home',
            component:  () => {
                if(user.isLoggedIn()) {
                    return import('./views/Home');
                }else {
                    return import('./views/Welcome');
                }
            },
        },
    ],
},
```

Comment: you need change isLoggedIn state when user logged out.
can you show isLoggedIn method code?

Comment: `export function isLoggedIn() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('app-vue-token');
    return token != null;
}` 

When I logged-out it will go to `/login`, the probem is when I click to `/` it still using **Auth.vue** & **Home.vue**.